# How do I retrieve os_log entries from an Apple Watch?

Tags: logging, apple-watch, watchos

I have added some debug logging to an Apple Watch app using `os_log`. However I cannot find any way to retrieve the information that it has logged from my Watch. Note I am using a real watch (not the simulator).

I am using Xcode 10.2.1 on MacOS 10.14.5 and my Watch is v4 with WatchOS 5.2.1. The Console app on my Macbook can (sometimes) connect to the watch but it shows no log entries of any kind from any app.

Example logging code: `os_log("hello world")`

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the `sysdiagnose` profile on the watch. You can find it at https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/profiles-and-logs/?name=sysdiagnose.